# Can you host/publish only the ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I'm new to API, I have created couple of APIs and a simple UI. Can I host only the APIs in my IIS, If I host only the APIs, can I see the list of APIs if I browse to http://localhost/api

at the moment I can access the APIs if I browse to http://localhost/api/Houses/200

Comment: What do you mean "host only"? What else are you worried about? What have you tried?

Comment: I published the Web Application and APIs within the project, but can I host only the APIs in IIS. So that if I browse to http://localhost/api I can see a list of APIs that are hosted?

Comment: refer to this link. I feel it is useful. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/

Comment: Put your Web API in a separate project. Then you can publish it independently of the rest of the application.

Comment: @Sailor Thank mate. I looked at this already. :) I have successfully hosted the hosted WebApplication. Maybe my question is invalid to begin with. To simplify things, if I browse to localhost/api, I can see a list of APIs that are hosted?

Comment: @mason Thank you. I will try this. Do you know where the APIs are stored when the project is published? as I can't see the controllers folder after I published the project

Comment: You shouldn't expect to see a controller folder. Think about what happens to code. The C# gets compiled to IL and placed in a DLL.

Comment: I think you are getting confused in your terminology.  The api is the project as a whole, and the controllers are endpoints.  Above http://localhost/api is likely the root of your api.  It is also likely you have multiple endpoints i.e. http://localhost/api/houses, http://localhost/api/streets, http://localhost/api/zipcodes.  I believe the question you want to ask is can I see a list of my endpoints, is that correct?

Comment: @Woot You are absolutely correct. Sorry for the confusion. How can I see a list of my endpoints? thank you so sorting this out.

Comment: Hi Guys, I published the APIs on its own, works fine. So if I'm not wrong, only way to see a list of my endpoints is to create a API Documentation? Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting a list of all your endpoints the easiest and safest way to do this (in my opinion) is to create help pages using Microsoft's help page nuget package.

Microsofts how to page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes sense.